# JTextField not working properly

Tags: java, swing, initialization, jframe, local-variables

I just want to run a swing application t display a textfield.
Following is the code when run the exceptions generated are :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at textf.<init>(textf.java:10)
at textf$1.run(textf.java:35)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help what to do.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class textf{
JTextField tf;
JFrame j;
textf(){
    new JFrame("TextField Demo");
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setSize(400,200);
    j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    tf=new JTextField("press<Enter>",20);

    j.add(tf);
    j.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String s[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new textf();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're never assigning a value to `j`, so it has the default value of `null`. When you try to dereference it in the second line of your constructor (`j.setDefaultCloseOperation(...)`) that therefore throws a `NullPointerException`. Note that this is before you even get to a `JTextField`...

Just change the first line of your constructor to:

```
j = new JFrame("TextField Demo");
```

After that, sort out both the indentation of your code and the naming of your class and variables, so you end up with more maintainable code :)

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please name a worldwide popular Java Desktop applications.Is there any scope in it??

Comment: @coder005: I don't see what that has to do with the question at all. Java is more widely used on the server side and in mobile (Android), but I'm sure there are some desktop apps which are reasonably popular too.

Comment: @JBNizet: I thought about that, but I feel that IDEs sort of shouldn't count as desktop apps for a platform. It smacks of nepotism, if you see what I mean.